# Removing white or light colors from matplotlib color palette

Tags: python, matplotlib

The [matplotlib color palettes](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) often feature white or very light colors which do not show up well on scatter or line plots.

I am making a plot in which I use

```
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
cmap = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.Blues)
plt.plot(x, y, c=cmap.to_rgba(z))
cbar = plt.colorbar(cmap)
```

to plot numerous lines. I want to modify the color palette to remove the first, say, 30% of the colors. How can this be achieved?

---

My solution, which is fairly poor, is to modify two of the lines as follows:

```
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-0.4, vmax=1)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cmap, boundaries=[0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily create a custom colormap using `LinearSegmentedColormap` and choosing the colors that you want (in this case, a subset of the original colormap)

```
min_val, max_val = 0.3,1.0
n = 10
orig_cmap = plt.cm.Blues
colors = orig_cmap(np.linspace(min_val, max_val, n))
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("mycmap", colors)
```

demo

```
gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(5,2))
ax1.imshow(gradient, cmap=orig_cmap, aspect='auto')
ax1.set_title('original')
ax2.imshow(gradient, cmap=cmap, aspect='auto')
ax2.set_title('custom')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: What if I need to specify the initial colors as floats? Is it still possible to select only a range from a larger colormap?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, my CMasher package provides a function that can make a sub-version of any colormap very easily, while also taking care of using enough color segments (https://cmasher.readthedocs.io/user/usage.html#sub-colormaps).

Comment: fantastic, this should be part of matplotlib by default